# Numpy matrix 4x4 @ Nx4

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to apply world transformation to a numpy matrix. However, I can't seem to find a numpy way to perform a 4x4 matrix multiplication by Nx4 vector where N is the number of vertices.

I have both tried **Nx4x4@Nx4** and **4x4@Nx4** multiplications. Sure, I could do this element wise but I'm hoping there's a smarter way to do this.

```
vertices = np.ones([VERTEX_COUNT, 4])
vertices[:, 0:3] = vertex_map[element.path_vertices]
matrix = np.full([VERTEX_COUNT, 4, 4], np.reshape(element.matrix, [4, 4]))

transformed = matrix @ vertices # dimension mismatch

# i would rather not do this
# matrix = np.reshape(element.matrix, [4, 4])
# transformed = np.array([matrix @ vertex for vertex in vertices])
```

Comment: `matrix @ vertices.T)`?

Comment: The last dimension of `A` has to match the 2nd to the last of `B`.  It is doing classic matrix multiplication on the last 2 dimensions.  Leading ones are just a `batch`.  Remember - rows with columns for a 2d matrices.  **(N,4)@(4,M)** works, because of the matching `4`.

Comment: You may need to study `np.matmul` docs to understand how dimension are handled.  Sometimes it's easier to use `np.einsum`.  In any case, you need a clear sense of which dimensions are shared (and summed) and which are just a 'batch'.  Your description isn't very clear.